# Передача переменных по ссылке из c# в dll c++

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно передавать переменные из проекта на c# в dll'ку написанную на c++, с помощью ссылок.
То есть, у меня есть переменные в шарпе которые я передам в dll, затем проделаю там с ними различные операции в различных функциях, и соответственно верну их новые значения обратно в шарп.

Comment: На будущее: [линк](http://microsin.net/programming/pc/marshalling-with-csharp-simple-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

По идее как-то так:

```
[DllImport("ImportDLL.dll")]
public static extern void MyFunction(ref int myInteger);
```